# Summing over a DataFrame with two conditions and multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame x with three columns;

```
    a   b   c    
1   1   10  4   
2   5   6   5   
3   4   6   5   
4   2   11  9         
5   1   2   10
```

... and a Series y of two values;

```
    t
1   3
2   7
```

Now I'd like to get a DataFrame z with two columns;

```
    t   sum_c     
1   3   18
2   7   13
```

... with t from y and sum_c the sum of c from x for all rows where t was larger than a and smaller than b.

Would anybody be able to help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a possible solution based on the given condition (the expected results listed in ur question dont quite line up with the given condition):

```
In[99]: df1

Out[99]: 
   a   b   c
0  1  10   4
1  5   6   5
2  4   6   5
3  2  11   9
4  1   2  10

In[100]: df2

Out[100]: 
   t
0  3
1  5
```

then write a function which would be used by pandas.apply() later:

```
In[101]: def cond_sum(x):
    return sum(df1['c'].ix[np.logical_and(df1['a']<x.ix[0],df1['b']>x.ix[0])])
```

finally:

```
In[102]: df3 = df2.apply(cond_sum,axis=1)

In[103]: df3
Out[103]: 
0    13
1    18
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Small tweak to your excellent answer: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : pd.Series([1,5,4,2,1]),'b' : pd.Series([10,6,6,11,2]),'c' : pd.Series([4,5,5,9,10])})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'t' : pd.Series([3,5])})
def cond_sum(x): return sum(df1['c'].ix[np.logical_and(df1['a']<x.ix[0],df1['b']>x.ix[0])])
pd.concat([df2,pd.DataFrame({'sum_c' :df2.apply(cond_sum,axis=1)})],axis = 1)

Comment: ah u r right.  there was a typo.  just made the change